# Run app on wake up

Tags: macos, macos-monterey

I'm using an Imac with Monterey. I need to run an app everytime i wake up my computer after sleep. I know how to use the Login items options to run an app after reboot, but i need to run everytime i put it to sleep and wake it up. Is there a way to do this ?

Looks like the Automator service can do this, but i don't know how.

Actually it's the Logitech mouse app that i need to run, because otherwise my configurations are not applied.

Thanks

Comment: A google search *"macos how to run an application on wake up"* returns many links that deal with the topic. Did you try some of the proposed solutions? If yes, which problems are you encountering?

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) Why not look into *why* the LogiOptions app isn't waking properly?

Comment: Could you give some feedback, please?

Comment: @PierU I still could not find a tutorial to do this

Comment: Check Sleepwatcher: https://www.bernhard-baehr.de/ . Apparently requires some knowledge of unix command-line